# htaccess exception for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, exception, subdomain

I have this line in my htaccess file: RewriteRule (.*) index.php
This catches all requests being sent to my site domain.com
Now i have created a subdomain blog.domain.com and i am getting an Internal server error. How can i add blog.domain.com as an exception in htaccess.

This is my whole htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/http-bind
RewriteRule (.*) /http-bind [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/google3ce18567a119af4.html
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to the top of your `RewriteCond` block.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/google3ce18567a119af4.html
```

This will only pass when the request is **not** for `blog.domain.com` and meets all of your current conditions.

As a side, I would encourage you to do something more like the following as opposed to your specific file checks.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This ensures that the request is not an existing file or directory. It's easier to maintain than whitelisting specific resources (e.g. google3ce18567a119af4.html, /ow_updates/, etc).